# Use Peoplecode to delete files from remote FTP site

Tags: java, peoplesoft, peoplecode

I am trying to use a PeopleCode app engine to delete files from a remote server.
GetAttachment would work except that I want to loop through a the whole directory on the server and match files like *march*.csv.

Also, I am needing to do this by date range.  *.csv between date 1 and date 2.

Get attachment seems to require that you know the file name and individually delete the files.
So pattern pattern matching will not work.

I can get the list and check dates using java objects:

Local JavaObject &joFile = CreateJavaObject("java.io.File", SFO_DEL_FTP_AET.FTPDIRECTORY);
Local JavaObject &joFileList;
Local JavaObject &reflectArray = GetJavaClass("java.lang.reflect.Array");
Local JavaObject &dttm_format = CreateJavaObject("java.text.SimpleDateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd");

but I can only use that with local servers.

Is there a way to actually connect to the server, then use the java objects?

Thanks,
JPS

Answer (score 1):

You could use Apache [Commons NET](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) library for this. One of the packages is intended for FTP/FTPS access.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(server, port);
ftpClient.login(user, pass);
 
FTPFile[] files = ftpClient.listFiles("/yourDir");
```

Once you get the file list, you could retrieve the name from the [`FTPFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html) object.

In order to delete a file, you could use FTPClient's [`deleteFile`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#deleteFile(java.lang.String)) method.

> `public boolean deleteFile(String pathname)`
>
> *Deletes a file on the FTP server. Parameters: pathname - The pathname of the file to be deleted.
> Returns: True if successfully completed, false if not.*

```
 
for (FTPFile file : files) 
{
    String fileName = file.getName();
    /*if (file.isDirectory()) 
       handle directory access*/
    
    //use getAttachment from the fileName
  
    //in order to delete a file, call FTPClient's deleteFile Method  
    //ftpClient.deleteFile(filePath);
}

ftpClient.logout();
ftpClient.disconnect();
```

You can [download the NET library here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/download_net.cgi)